# Using metafunctions to iterate many values

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to imitate this arithmetic expression using metafunctions:
[image]

Essentially, I want random real numbers from `-1<0<1` for **x** and **theta** whilst **y** takes any **positve** or **negative** value from `-20<0<20`.

This is what I have tried:

```
am_thirteen <-function(x, y, theta){
  
  x1=runif(x, 0, 1)
  y2=runif(y, 0, 20)
  theta3=runif(theta, 0, 1)
  lapply(
    x1, y2, theta3, 
    FUN = function(x1, y2, theta3){
  (-(1/theta3)*log10(1+(((exp(-theta3*x1)-1)*(exp(-theta3*y2)-1))/(exp(-theta3)-1))))

      })
}
```

then:

```
lapply(c(10, 10, 10), am_thirteen)
```

error:

> Error in runif(y, 0, 20) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

I expect the output to be like this when I call the function likeso:

```
am_thirteen <-function(x, y, theta){
     (-(1/theta)*log10(1+(((exp(-theta*x)-1)*(exp(-theta*y)-1))/(exp(-theta)-1))))
 }

am_thirteen(runif(30, -1, 1),runif(30, -1, 1) ,runif(30, -1, 1) )
 [1] -0.1171828665 -0.1084171900 -0.2441978216  0.0256141946  0.0131042671  0.0844813069 -0.2898303502 -0.0051398158  0.0211143988  0.0667284968  0.0956009788 -0.2560234695
[13]  0.0039000563  0.0438593991 -0.0405444828 -0.1644587072 -0.0740161357  0.0652280253  0.0009757007  0.1854526942 -0.0905563222  0.0223378333 -0.0274033047 -0.2896201555
[25] -0.0173795526 -0.1840047563           NaN -0.1889213392 -0.0772152240 -0.0233664868
```

Comment: "I want to random integers from -1<0<1" -- but `0` is the only integer in that range. Did you mean real number? Or -- did you mean a randomly chosen integer from the set `{-1,0,1}`?

Comment: Ah yes, I meant real number. Thanks for watching out on that

Comment: But, if you want real numbers, why are you using `round`? In any event, if you want to apply your function on a grid of randomly chosen points, look into `expand.grid`

Comment: I had to double check the meaning for integer and real number again. Round is not necessary, I actually imitated that part from a previous code, because I had different intentions for it during then. Seems I didn't rationalise with my code neither with what I want. You can ignore `round`, and aim for the real numbers for `-1<0<1` and integers for **y** so `{-20:0:20}` denoting `seq(-20, 20, 1)`

Comment: @JohnColeman `expand.grid` is new to me although it looks very refreshing. However, whilst using ```expand.grid(am_thirteen(4, 4, 4))``` I get 4 columns and many repetitions, is this an issue with my function?

Comment: I actually did not try the code out, it seems that it works fine by doing: `am_thirteen(10, 10, 10)` then using `unlist` if I really wanted to. I was following a similar argument by someone else so I had thought that I would need to call the function within `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like

```
am_thirteen <- function(x, y, theta) {
  x1 <- runif(x, 0, 1)
  y2 <- runif(y, 0, 20)
  theta3 <- runif(theta, 0, 1)
  -(1 / theta3) * log10(1 + (((exp(-theta3 * x1) - 1) * (exp(-theta3 * y2) - 1)) / (exp(-theta3) - 1)))
}
```

such that

```
> am_thirteen(30, 30, 30)
 [1] 0.24717749 1.05846557 0.45755718 0.66018800 0.03834795 0.39526527
 [7] 1.99589251 3.43298477 0.56534793 1.01813706 0.49402778 0.53281734
[13] 1.15933195 2.30322906 0.12077730 0.06233150 0.05681387 0.32175138
[19] 1.39598926 0.63679915 0.77333056 0.03321481 0.31202521 0.83615194
[25] 0.64084402 0.69740361 0.61896551 2.28605706 0.92365230 0.21639357
```